# How can I add overlay buttons to an ar scene in A-Frame using ar.js?

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I am using ar.js in my scene as it works in IOS and I want to add one or two overlay buttons on mobile screen (not in 3d scene) which users can click when in AR, for different purposes such as change object color etc, but can't find a way to do it. I have added the buttons and their corresponding CSS, but whenever I click enter AR, the buttons do not show in AR. I had initially used ar-hit-test for its DOM_overlay and was able to get buttons visible in AR, but as it doesn't work in IOS out of the box, that wasn't working for me. Would be grateful if someone has a solution to this as have been trying to figure it out for days now. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="nextbutton">
    <h2>Next Model</h2>
    </div>`
<a-scene arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false">
<a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```